# Question regarding expectation value of energy and gibbs factor

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In lecture we introduced the average energy for a single particle as $$E = \langle \varepsilon \rangle = \frac{\int d \varepsilon g(\varepsilon) e^{- \beta \varepsilon} \varepsilon}{Z_1}$$
where $Z_1 = \int d \varepsilon e^{- \beta \varepsilon}$. In the case of $g(\varepsilon) = 1$ the above calculation can be simplified and you would get $$E = k_B T$$ as the result of the integral. When you consider $N$ indistinguishable particles, I would have no problem assuming that $$E = N \langle \varepsilon \rangle = Nk_BT$$ since this still makes sense to me. However if I consider the above expression for the expectation value now integrated for $N$ particles meaning that if they are not interacting $Z = Z_1^N$ and $$E = \langle \varepsilon \rangle = \frac{\int d \varepsilon g(\varepsilon) e^{- \beta \varepsilon} \varepsilon}{Z_1^N}$$ where $\varepsilon = \sum_{i=1}^N \varepsilon_i$ and $d \varepsilon = \prod_{i=1}^{N} d \varepsilon_i$ then I get a strange result which is not $Nk_BT$, even though in my head it's still the expectation value for the energy for $N$ particles. So my first question would be: What did I do wrong in the second calculation? My second question overall is also: How does the definition of the expectation value here account for indistinguishable particles? Normally you would introduce a Gibbs factor in the way that $\tilde{Z} = \frac{Z}{N!}$ which would change the result for the second calculation while the first calculation isn't affected because we are only looking at single particle partition function/average energy. I would be grateful for someone telling me where my thinking went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with your second question

> How does the definition of the expectation value here account for indistinguishable particles?

It doesn't. What you have calculated here is not the expected energy of $N$ indistinguishable particles, it is the expectation of the energy for $N$ distinguishable particles, which happen to have the same available energies and degenerates. For truly indistinguishable particles you could not factor the degeneracy $g$, as if any two particles had the same energy you would get a reduced degeneracy to avoid over-counting configurations with the particles exchanged. This is what results in the factor of $\frac{1}{N!}$ when calculating the combined partition function.

For the frist part

> What did I do wrong in the second calculation?

I don't know what happened in your calculation. You have not written down exactly what you did. For the $N$ identical-but-distinguishable particles discussed above, with $g(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\dots\varepsilon_n) = 1$ (As a side note $g$ should have units of $[E]^{-N}$, but we will ignore this and assume we have somehow normalized our energy to get a dimensionless $\varepsilon$), we can optain $E = Nk_BT$ as follows
\begin{align}
E &= \frac{1}{Z_1^N} \int \left(\prod_i d\varepsilon_i\right) \sum_j \varepsilon_j e^{-\beta \sum_k \varepsilon_k}\\
&= \frac{1}{Z_1^N} \sum_j\int \left(\prod_{i} d\varepsilon_i\right)  \varepsilon_j e^{-\beta \sum_k \varepsilon_k}\\
&= \frac{1}{Z_1^N} \sum_j\int d\varepsilon_j \varepsilon_j e^{-\beta \varepsilon_j}\;\int\left(\prod_{i\ne j} d\varepsilon_i \right)e^{-\beta \sum_{k\ne j}\varepsilon_k}\\
&= \frac{1}{Z_1^{N-1}} \sum_j \langle \varepsilon_j \rangle Z_1^{N-1}\\
&= N k_B T
\end{align}

Comment: I have misscalculated the integrals without realizing that this is just a product of the 1-particle partition functions, but it makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up!